# How to reduce the size of main.js file in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, filesize, deferred-loading

I am using the **deferred concept** to reduce the size of the `main.js` file in the web build. But it only reduces the file size **from 3.5MB to 3.1MB**. It didn't help me that much. Is my implementation wrong? How can I reduce the size of the `main.js` file?

[image: Web Build Directory]

**Main Code:**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  navigationServiceController.registerLazySingleton(() => NavigationService());
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: "tolk2gotasker", options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await getFlagList();
  await gettingLanguage();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  runApp(const Inizilation());
}

class Inizilation extends StatelessWidget {
  const Inizilation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
      initialRoute: initialPage(),
      title: "T2G Tasker",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scrollbarTheme: const ScrollbarThemeData(
          thickness: MaterialStatePropertyAll<double>(0),
          trackVisibility: MaterialStatePropertyAll<bool>(false),
          thumbVisibility: MaterialStatePropertyAll<bool>(false),
        ),
        fontFamily: "AvenirLTDStd",
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: kWhite),
        primaryColor: kOrange,
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        applyElevationOverlayColor: true,
        focusColor: Colors.transparent,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: kBlack,
        ),
      ),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale("en", "US"),
        Locale("nl", "NL"),
        Locale('ru', 'RU'),
      ],
      scrollBehavior: RemoveGlowEffect().copyWith(scrollbars: false),
      enableLog: true,
      defaultTransition: Transition.fade,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) =>
          MainLayout(child: child),
      key: navigatorKey,
      onUnknownRoute:
          navigationServiceController<NavigationService>().generateUnknownRoute,
      onGenerateRoute:
          navigationServiceController<NavigationService>().generateRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

**Main Layout Code:**

```
class MainLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainLayout({super.key, required this.child});

  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        navigationServiceController<NavigationService>().navigateBack();
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: const CommonAppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: SizedBox(width: width < 700 ? width : 700, child: child),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: const CommonBottomBar()),
    );
  }
}
```

**Navigation Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/ActualDurationPage/actual_duration.dart'
    deferred as actual_duration;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/CommonFiles/constants.dart';
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/ExtraAmountPage/extra_amount.dart'
    deferred as extra_amount;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/InAppNotificationPage/in_app_notificaiton_page.dart'
    deferred as in_app_notificaiton_page;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/LoginPage/account_register.dart'
    deferred as account_register;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/LoginPage/forget_email_trigger.dart'
    deferred as forget_email_trigger;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/LoginPage/forget_email_trigger_confirmation.dart'
    deferred as forget_email_trigger_confirmation;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/LoginPage/password_page.dart'
    deferred as password_page;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/LogoutPage/logout.dart' deferred as logout;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/ProfilePage/profile_page.dart'
    deferred as profile_page;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/Routing/page_name.dart';
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/TaskCompletionPage/task_completion.dart'
    deferred as task_completion;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/TaskListPage/task_list.dart'
    deferred as task_list;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/LoginPage/email_check.dart'
    deferred as email_check;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/SignaturePage/signature.dart'
    deferred as signature;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/SplashScreen/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/TaskDetailPage/task_details_page.dart'
    deferred as task_details;
import 'package:tolk2go_tasker/binding.dart';

class NavigationService {
  Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName) {
    return Get.toNamed(routeName)!;
  }

  Future<dynamic> navigateOffAll(String routeName) {
    return Get.offAllNamed(routeName)!;
  }

  Future<dynamic> navigateUntil(String routeName) {
    return Get.offNamedUntil(routeName, (route) => false)!;
  }

  Future<dynamic> navigateOff(String routeName) {
    return Get.offNamed(routeName)!;
  }

  void navigateBack() {
    switch (Get.currentRoute) {
      case registerScreen:
        navigateOff(emailCheckScreen);
        break;
      case forgotPasswordEmailScreen:
        navigateOff(emailCheckScreen);
        break;
      case forgotPasswordScreen:
        navigateOff(forgotPasswordEmailScreen);
        break;
      case taskDetailsScreen:
        taskListPage();
        break;
      default:
        Get.back();
    }
  }

  void splashScreenPage() {
    navigateTo(splashScreen);
  }

  void emailPage() {
    navigateOffAll(emailCheckScreen);
  }

  void passwordPage() {
    navigateTo(passwordScreen);
  }

  void registerPage() {
    navigateTo(registerScreen);
  }

  void forgotEmailTriggerPage() {
    navigateTo(forgotPasswordEmailScreen);
  }

  void forgotPasswordPage() {
    navigateTo(forgotPasswordScreen);
  }

  void taskListPage() {
    navigateOffAll(taskListScreen);
  }

  void taskDetailsPage() {
    navigateTo(taskDetailsScreen);
  }

  void actualDurationPage() {
    navigateTo(actualDurationScreen);
  }

  void extraAmountPage() {
    navigateTo(extraAmountScreen);
  }

  void signaturePage() {
    navigateTo(signatureScreen);
  }

  void taskComplitionPage() {
    navigateTo(taskCompletionScreen);
  }

  void notificationPage() {
    navigateTo(inAppNotificaitonScreen);
  }

  void profilePage() {
    navigateTo(profileScreen);
  }

  void logoutPage() {
    navigateOffAll(logoutScreen);
  }

  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    deferredPage(settings.name!);
    switch (settings.name) {
      case splashScreen:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: splashScreen,
            page: () => const SplashScreen(),
            binding: SplashScreenBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }

      case passwordScreen:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: passwordScreen,
            page: () => password_page.PasswordPage(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case registerScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = kLanguage.value.register;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: registerScreen,
            page: () => account_register.AccountRegister(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case forgotPasswordEmailScreen:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: forgotPasswordEmailScreen,
            page: () => forget_email_trigger.ForgotEmailTrigger(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case forgotPasswordScreen:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: forgotPasswordScreen,
            page: () => forget_email_trigger_confirmation
                .ForgotEmailTriggerConfirmation(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case taskListScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          enableAppBar.value = true;
          enableBottomBar.value = true;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: taskListScreen,
            page: () => task_list.TaskListPage(),
            binding: TaskListBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case taskDetailsScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: taskDetailsScreen,
            page: () => task_details.TaskDetailsPage(),
            binding: TaskDetailsBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case actualDurationScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: actualDurationScreen,
            page: () => actual_duration.ActualDuration(),
            binding: ActualDurationBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case extraAmountScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: extraAmountScreen,
            page: () => extra_amount.ExtraAmount(),
            binding: ExtraAmountBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case signatureScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: signatureScreen,
            page: () => signature.Signature(),
            binding: SignatureBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case taskCompletionScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: taskCompletionScreen,
            page: () => task_completion.TaskComplition(),
            binding: TaskCompletionBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case inAppNotificaitonScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: inAppNotificaitonScreen,
            page: () => in_app_notificaiton_page.InAppNotification(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case profileScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: profileScreen,
            page: () => profile_page.ProfilePage(),
            binding: ProfileBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case logoutScreen:
        {
          prefs.clear();
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          commonBottomBarViewModel.taskerName.value = "";
          enableBottomBar.value = false;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: logoutScreen,
            page: () => logout.LogoutPage(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      default:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: emailCheckScreen,
            page: () => email_check.EmailCheck(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
    }
  }

  Route<dynamic> generateUnknownRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
    enableAppBar.value = true;
    kLoginStatus = prefs.getBool("loginStatus") ?? false;
    if (kLoginStatus) {
      enableBottomBar.value = true;
      return GetPageRoute(
        routeName: taskListScreen,
        page: () => task_list.TaskListPage(),
        binding: TaskListBinding(),
        settings: settings,
      );
    } else {
      return GetPageRoute(
        routeName: emailCheckScreen,
        page: () => email_check.EmailCheck(),
        binding: LoginBinding(),
        settings: settings,
      );
    }
  }

  void redirectingToTaskDetailsPage() {
    if (Get.previousRoute == "/") {
      commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
      taskDetailsPage();
    }
  }

  Future<void> deferredPage(String pageName) async {
    switch (pageName) {
      case emailCheckScreen:
        {
          await email_check.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case passwordScreen:
        {
          await password_page.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case registerScreen:
        {
          await account_register.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case forgotPasswordEmailScreen:
        {
          await forget_email_trigger.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case forgotPasswordScreen:
        {
          await forget_email_trigger_confirmation.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case taskListScreen:
        {
          await task_list.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case taskDetailsScreen:
        {
          await task_details.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case actualDurationScreen:
        {
          await actual_duration.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case extraAmountScreen:
        {
          await extra_amount.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case signatureScreen:
        {
          await signature.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case taskCompletionScreen:
        {
          await task_completion.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case inAppNotificaitonScreen:
        {
          await in_app_notificaiton_page.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
      case profileScreen:
        {
          await profile_page.loadLibrary();
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say that it's quite okay to have that large file size, as Flutter's been compiled to JavaScript, which produces not most effective JS code. I'd probably suggest trying to simplify your switch-case logic, as it is hard to read and maintain and it even might cause an increase in the generated file size.

Comment: @DmytroPopov I am using the `builder` property in the `MaterialApp` widget to make the header and the footer persistent. I need the switch case to change the body. Each case is a separate page. So, I can't do anything about it. So far, I can change the `switch` to `if else`. Changing from `switch` to `if else` will reduce the size? And I am trying to reduce the size of the `main.js` file So that it can reduce the web's initial loading time.

Comment: You may try using something like a functional implementation of [Strategy(Policy) design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) to remove switch-cases. The switch-case in the `deferredPage` function can be simplified using just a Map, as you don't have any additional logic there.

Comment: [Enhanced Enums](https://dart.dev/language/enum) can help you a lot with the Strategy implementation. They are also much more convenient than strings when describing something like app pages.

Comment: @DmytroPopov he is not asking for design advice. And 3mb main file is definitely not enjoyable for mobile web. You are comments are completely off-topic.

Comment: The code is unreadable and it was unnecessary to add it here. The main problem appears to be in the dart2js compiler itself. Try compiling a simple hello world function in Dart to JS with a maximum level optimization, and the size will increase dramatically. However, in Flutter 3.10 they have increased the loading speed, and now it loads much faster on average.

Comment: Yes, After upgrading to the latest flutter version the initial loading become faster and I have also added a loader to it.